# Powershell match file names and append

Tags: powershell

I have two files each in a seperate folder.

FileA and FileA_dynamic

I'm looking for a way to match these filenames and append FileA with the matching FileA_dynamic. Keeping in mind there are other files in the same directories with different names with the same structure. I'd like to take all of them and append them with their counterpart.

Anyone with any ideas? I've been battling with this for hours today.

```
$dynamicpath = "Path_to_dynamic files"
$staticpath = "Path_to_static files"

$staticfile = Get-childitem -Path $staticpath
$dynamicfile = Get-childitem -Path $dynamicpath | where-object {$_.Name -like '*_dynamic'}
foreach ($line in $dynamicfile.Name){

$dynamicoutput = $line.split('_')[0]
}

foreach ($staticitem in $staticfile.Name -match $dynamicoutput) {

do something

}
```

Comment: Do the files in static path have the same extension as the files in the dynamic path?

Comment: Hi Theo, yes they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the static and dynamic files have the same extension,this should work:

```
$dynamicpath = "Path_to_dynamic files"
$staticpath  = "Path_to_static files"

# get a list of basename prefixes of the dynamic files
$dynamicFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dynamicpath -Filter '*_dynamic.*' -File) | ForEach-Object { ($_.BaseName -split '_dynamic')[0] }
# get an array of FileInfo objects of the static files with basenames matching the dynamic prefixes above
$staticFiles  =  Get-ChildItem -Path $staticpath -File | Where-Object { $dynamicFiles -contains $_.BaseName }

# loop through the static files we found and add their content to the dynamic counterparts
foreach ($file in $staticFiles) {
    # create the full path to the matching dynamic file
    $dynFile = Join-Path -Path $dynamicpath -ChildPath ('{0}_dynamic{1}' -f $file.BaseName, $file.Extension)

    Write-Host "Adding content of $($file.FullName) to $($dynFile)"
    Add-Content -Path $dynFile -Value (Get-Content -Path $file.FullName)
}
```

Comment: Awsome thanks Theo, I'll give this a go tomorrow morning and will give you guys some feedback. Thank you so much for all the help

Comment: @Hein P.s. one of your comments confuse me.. If you need the content of the **dynamic** file to be added to the **static** file, then just replace the order of the files here:


`Add-Content -Path $file.FullName -Value (Get-Content -Path $dynFile)`

Comment: Think i got a little messed up with the append bit XD

Comment: i realised something this morning. If this is a dropzone for dynamic files. How would i go about skipping these already ammended when new scripts are dropped in the dynamic folder?

Answer (score 0):

Hein,

This should work:

```
$dynamicpath = "G:\Test\Dynamic"
$staticpath = "G:\Test\Static\*.*"

Get-childitem -Path $staticpath -Filter "*.txt" |
ForEach-Object {

  $FName = $_.Name.Split(".")[0]
  $DynPath = "$dynamicpath\$($FName)_dynamic.txt"

  If (Test-Path -Path $DynPath ) {
     "Process me: $DynPath"
     $DynContent = Get-Content "$DynPath"
     $StaticContent = Get-Content "$($_.FullName)"
     $DynContent += $StaticContent
     Set-Content -path "$DynPath" -value $DynContent
  }
  Else{ "Don't Process me: $DynPath"}

}
```

Note: the -Filter on the Get-ChildItem. I assume your files are of a specific type and this will limit memory usage and processing time. I also assumed that the joining process was a simple concatenation of the file contents, if not you'll need more specific logic. You might also consider deleting the Static file after writing it to the dynamic file so you don't reprocess it if you run again.

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much for this. To give you some background. File paths remain static. I'm trying to append two sql script files. "spload" with "spload_dynamic" The files all have the same starting name but there are many of them with all different names. The dynamic sql script is dropped in a static location where we kick off a job to append the original sql script file.The process of this can't really change. I don't really have any specific preference on how i get there, as long as i can manage to add the content of all "scriptfiles_dynamic" with their "scriptfiles" counterpart

Comment: just wanted to let you know your piece of code also works for me, thanks so much!